# Rotate the screen close the app (instead of showing landscape layout)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a folder layout-land where I have put a modified copy of my main.xml layout (modified to display the layout in landscape). So I have main.xml in res/layout and modified main.xml in res/layout-land.

When I rotate the phone in landscape before running my app, the good activity is displayed (same for vertical), but if I rotate while running the app, the activity "disappear" and the home screen is displayed...

This only on main.xml, not on preferences screen (when I rotate, the screen rotate).

It's not a FC: *activity is still running in background* no, app is killed by me!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that my main.xml layout contains a tab layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem : when I rotate the screen, void onDestroy is called. In that void, I kill the process, that's why the app ends (in fact I was wrong, the app doesn't continue in background, process is killed by me).

And I have found some answers in stackoverflow to avoid execute everything in onCreate after screen rotation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your layout folder to layout-port. This might allow it to distinguish better.

If still having the same problem, you might need to provide your error message or your codes.

Comment: Sorry, it's worse : stil have home screen when rotate on main activity, but now if I rotate on preferences, I have a FC (before screen rorates normally on preferences).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have added the code of my vertical layout (landscape is the same except position of buttons.

Comment: On my previous version, I had screen-orientation vertical in Manifest. I tried "sensor" but same problem, so I removed screen-orientation from Manifest :

Comment: Here are the choices, but I don't know what to try          android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "user" | "behind" |
                                     "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                     "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
                                     "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
                                     "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor"]